# c# MySql Not Writing utf-8 Characters

Tags: c#, mysql, database, encoding, utf-8

I am having a problem with writing a string to a mysql database that contains a utf-8 character. Everything before the character gets written to the table, but the character and everything after it is not there.

I have checked the character sets of the database and the default collation is `utf8_general_ci` and the default characterset is `utf8`. The column being written to is type `longtext` with the collation `utf8_general_ci`.

I have also tried adding `SET NAMES utf8;` to the query but this did not change the result.

Here is an example of the code being run:

```
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into tablename (BodyText) values (@p1)", connection as MySqlConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.Text }) 
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", BodyText);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The connection string is:

```
 "SERVER=xx;DATABASE=xx;USER=xx;PASSWORD=xx;Pooling=true;Validate Connection=true;CHARSET=UTF8"
```

And the text that is attempting to write to the table is "Thank you! I saw it as a 2  more text...", and what is written to the table is "Thank you! I saw it as a 2 ".

Any help on the matter would be appreciated.

Update: After further research the problem appears to be that the base utf8 encoding in MySql does not support 4-byte characters (of which  is). The solutions to this are either to update the MySql database to use utf8mb4 or remove the characters from the string before writing to the table. The problem with the second solution is on a large codebase this check would have to be done everywhere text is written to the database. Any suggestions on how to handle this issue would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can *probably* to this to change from utf8 to utf8mb4 in a table without losing or mangling any data:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col ... CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 ...;
```

(Where the '...' is the stuff currently used to define the column, such as `LONGTEXT`.)  You might want to specify the collation at the same time.

If that fails, this will probably work:

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col LONGBLOB ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col LONGTEXT ... CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 ...;
```

If `col` is in any indexes, you might want to DROP INDEX in the first ALTER and ADD INDEX in the second. (This is for efficiency and possibly to avoid index limitations.)